# Datetime format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" in visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, datetime, visual-studio-2015

I have column in table, with `datetime` type.

Then I'm  reporting this data from table using `SQL Server Data Tools 2015`.

I want that in visual studio, displayed date and time in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, though, in visual studio, when I look `Text Box Properties`->`Number`, there `Date` and `Time` formats are separated.

Question: how can I format text box in visual studio, for displaying `datetime` value as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` ?

Comment: Did you try "DateFormat" in your transact query?

Comment: I need "DateFormat"  in my query? default format in DB table, already is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. I just need same format for visual studios "Text Box"  item.

Comment: If you set the `Text Box Properties` as `Text`, I believe the format will be fine coming from the database. Did you try that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this simple query

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY --Day/Month/Year ... you can write YMD or another combination
```

If you want to use CONVERT in your SELECT clause you can use:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 100) -- mon dd yyyy hh:mmAM (or PM) – Oct  2 2008 11:01AM          
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy - 10/02/2008                  
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) -- yyyy.mm.dd – 2008.10.02  
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 105) -- dd-mm-yyyy
```

And finally, visit [Date and Time styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)